# Don't shed a tear when I'm gone

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My name is a thing you might do to a tune
>   Or a thing you might find in a hot air balloon
>
> Gravity first makes me hold on quite tight
>   I follow a street to find action at night
>
> See me you may, in the streets of L.A.,
>   Embroiled in a blood-feud to this very day
>
> If I spot a pedestrian following me
>   I show off just how toned my pecs and abs be
>
> It seems that whenever I drink tea at all
>   That afterward I tend to stumble and fall
>
> I followed a lead Democrat I adore
>   Til he said I was just a conservative bore
>
> One final request I have for you, my friend
>   I'm planning ahead — all our days, some day, end
>   If they lay me to rest in a grave with a stone
>   On that marker I want one word, one word alone
>   Just my name on the stone to remember me by
>   And as epitaph to how I hope I shall lie

**What is my name?**

Comment: Why are you leaving us? ;_;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> RIP

---

My name is a thing you might do to a tune

> RIP is slang for copying music.

Or a thing you might find in a hot air balloon

> Balloons can have RIPS in them.

Gravity first makes me hold on quite tight

> GRIP means to hold on tight.

I follow a street to find action at night

> STRIP refers to a commercially developed area with lots of nightlife.

See me you may, in the streets of L.A.,
Embroiled in a blood-feud to this very day

> CRIPS are a violent street gang who feud with the Bloods (Thanks, Alconja).

If I spot a pedestrian following me
I show off just how toned my pecs and abs be

> RIPPED means having toned muscles.

It seems that whenever I drink tea at all
That afterward I tend to stumble and fall

> TRIP means stumble.

I followed a lead Democrat I adore
Til he said I was just a conservative bore

> DRIP means a bore.

One final request I have for you, my friend
I'm planning ahead — all our days, some day, end
If they lay me to rest in a grave with a stone
On that marker I want one word, one word alone
Just my name on the stone to remember me by
And as epitaph to how I hope I shall lie

> RIP means Rest In Peace.

The title,

> like the final stanza, refers to someone passing away.
>
>  There is also a pun on *tear*, meaning RIP (I missed this, but Rubio pointed it out in The Sphinx's Lair).

Comment: I think the blood-feud in the streets of LA is referring to [the crips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crips) ("C" + me you may...).